# Insert Login IP Ranges using apex in salesforce

Tags: apex

Is it possible to insert to Login IP ranges via apex?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any directly callable API.

There is a `ProfileLoginIpRange` class defined in the [Metadata API Developer’s
Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_meta.pdf). From Apex, you can use the [MetadataService class](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls) from this project [financialforcedev/apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) to insert the ranges providing you are working in a context where web service calls are allowed e.g. in a controller.

(This doesn't relate to your requirement, but there is an example of using apex-mdapi for another purpose [here](https://force201.wordpress.com/2015/06/01/picklist-values-by-record-type-for-angularjs-ui/) that might help you.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make callout either to Metadata API or try to use some other approach: imitating request which is sent from UI when you click Save button.

In any case you need first to add Remote Site Settings first to your organization and you had to do this manually.

I was trying to automatize actions like that and in my several packages I am preparing some links which user can click to save Remote Site Settings or Login IP Ranges.

I guess using Metadata API might be simpler but sending request which imitates UI Save button click is also possible.