# Set Login IP Ranges using Apex

Tags: apex

I wonder is it possible to set Login IP Ranges using Apex code? Is there any api for that?

Comment: Please check this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78313/insert-login-ip-ranges-using-apex-in-salesforce

Comment: Ok, thank you :)

Comment: Marking for closure as a duplicate, @mardok - in future, please always check for similar questions before posting one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make callout either to Metadata API or try to use some other approach: imitating request which is sent from UI when you click Save button.

In any case you need first to add Remote Site Settings first to your organization and you had to do this manually.

I was trying to automatize actions like that and in my several packages I am preparing some links which user can click to save Remote Site Settings or Login IP Ranges.

I guess using Metadata API might be simpler but sending request which imitates UI Save button click is also possible.

Comment: Do you know which Api calls I could use?